# Moving only data from SQL Server 2000 to 2012 check list

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000, core-data-migration

I need to move the production data between two servers from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012.

The database has already been moved perfectly. The production data needs to move overnight and be ready to be used the following day. So the plan is to do it as below:

1. Moving the data of all the config tables.
2. Moving the data of the other table. Here comes one of the problems: what should I do with the identity column? Almost all the tables has identity column and in some cases they are the foreign keys. How should this be handled?
3. Scripting the jobs as create and run and create all the jobs disable.
4. Move the SSIS database and config table.
5. Update the connections inside the SSIS packages and deploy them on the new server.

Is there anything else I should take into consideration? How to do the second step error free?

Comment: You can insert the existing identity values into a table with an identity column by using the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT (tablename) ON`. Only one table at a time - and turn it off again using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT (tablename) OFF` right after you're done. That should take care of the identity values

Comment: How are you moving the data? Manually, using exported files? Or are you connecting to the SQL 2000 DB using SSIS, and using a data pump to transfer the data? Or ???

Comment: @LaughingVergil Planning to do it manually , basically I want to run a script and start by truncating all the tables, and then insert into tables on the new server from the old server one by one.the main problem is how deal with Foreign Key Constraint. how can I truncate tables regardless to FK?

Comment: @marc_s , Thanks Marc_s. did a test with no problem.what about the FK contraint when truncating the tables?

Comment: This can be done in the Import Wizard - you just need to know what (hidden in an optional area) options to pick. I'll write this into an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the Import/Export wizard will import this data cleanly. And if you understand SSIS programming, you can edit it to automatically import the data from the different files.

First, let's do the basic import. The start is the same as the normal import - Right-Click the database in SSMS, choose Import data, select a flat file (with the table name + .txt as the name, this will automatically associate the import with the proper table in the destination database), set up the columns for the input file -- column names and data types matching the names and data types in the destination table so correct associations are made).

In setting up the destination, you will have one difference. First choose the correct destination type, server name, and authentication, then pick the destination DB. On the Select Source Tables and Views screen:
[image: Select Source Tables and Views screen]
and ensure that you have the correct source and destination chosen. Then (***important part starts here***) click on the Edit Mappings button. You will be taken to this screen:
[image: Column Mappings screen]
Select the correct handling of the rows (append or delete-then-add), and **click the Enable identity insert** checkbox **ON** (***End of the part that answers your questions***) and click OK.

If everything is correct on the Review page, choose whether or not to save the package (this is useful if you want to automate the process) and run the package.

*Et voila*, your data is imported, the Identity fields are imported correctly, and everything is good.